# Is it possible to enable -fae/--fail-at-end by default?

Tags: maven

I know I can instruct Maven to keep going after a failure with the -fae/--fail-at-end command-line option. Is there a way to set this behaviour as default for a given module?

Some background:
I'm moving from an Ant build to a Maven-based build, and the other developers on the team are used to the build completing even when there are failed unit tests. With a ~200-module product, the build takes a fair amount of time, and it would be ideal if developers could see *all* failing tests from the beginning, without having to remember to add the -fae option.

From reading the Maven docs, I get the feeling that the answer is a resounding "no", but I just want to cover my bases and make sure there isn't some sort of undocumented way to do this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip test failures you can use property `maven.test.failure.ignore`. Of course you can use this property per module if you have parent and children poms.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful, however failing tests are then incorrectly marked as successful. This is different from the behaviour of -fae, which I would prefer.

Comment: Maven in standard configuration uses surefire plugin for tests - it generates XML file with information if test failed and what tests. Most of CI tools can parse surefire XMLs to present these statistics on nice charts and show how many test failed.

Comment: Yes, this is useful for CI (and will be useful for our Hudson CI build), but not at all useful for local developer builds. If they have maven.test.feailure.ignore set, run the build (with failing unit tests), determine (incorrectly) that the build was successful, then they will commit broken tests to source control and break the CI build. I suppose the only reasonable options are to either force users to run their builds with -fae on the command line, or provide a .bat or .cmd script which provides that option.

Comment: I know what you mean. But you want to keep consistent with previous behaviour - did previous approach include listing at end all failed tests? If not it is similar to maven.test.failure.ignore. And as I remember " failing tests are then incorrectly marked as successful" it is not true - build of module is marked as successful but not failed tests.

Comment: And it seems there is one conflict in your approach: local build is required before every commit but you doesn't care about failed tests. I like approach that CI server is used to run quick checks build - as developer time is precious ;) and compilation errors you can see in IDE (I very dislike red errors in IDE, and slightly yellow errors) so on CI you can see what test failed. Also when other developers update sources they can see on CI what is latest safe revision.

Comment: I do care about failed tests, and this is the advantage of using -fae. The -fae behaviour marks failed tests as failed, and the rollup status at the end of the build is a failed status, as one would expect. The only advantage is that the reactor continues after failures, allowing more modules to build and tests to run (if possible). That provides a more complete picture IMO.

Comment: As for waiting to see the unit test result in the CI build, in our project, CI takes 20-30mins to complete, which is far too long to wait to see if tests are broken. For now, however, my approach will be to get developers to either add -fae on the commandline or have them follow Maven's (quite helpful) instructions on a failed build to continue the reactor where it left off after fixing the tests.

Comment: Since it seems like maven.test.failure.ignore is the only available alternative, I'm marking this as answered. In the meantime, I've logged http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5342

Answer (score 2):

After checking out the Maven source code, I can confirm this cannot be configured by default.

An existing issue is opened on the Maven tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5342 (please vote if you still want it -- just noticed you did open it so you cannot vote on it ;) )...

Regards,