# Alternative place to specify mvn --fail-at-end command line option?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, multi-module

We have a multi-module Maven project, and (at least by default) we want to build this using `--fail-at-end`.  Must this always be passed on the command line, or can this also be specified somehow in the (root) `pom.xml` file, or perhaps in a `settings.xml` file, or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

There is an old answer to this here:
[Is it possible to enable -fae/--fail-at-end by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205720/is-it-possible-to-enable-fae-fail-at-end-by-default)

However, times change. A method you can try is to modify your Maven batch or shell file to enable default arguments that will be run with every execution.

You can find the original Jira issue here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5342

On Windows, you define an environment variable MAVEN_DEFAULT_ARGS that includes switches such as the ones that you always want to run and modify the Maven batch file in the bin folder:

```
...
%MAVEN_JAVA_EXE% %MAVEN_OPTS% -classpath %CLASSWORLDS_JAR% "-Dclassworlds.conf=%M2_HOME%\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.home=%M2_HOME%" %CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER% %MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS% %MAVEN_DEFAULT_ARGS%
...
```

On Unix based systems add a parameter MAVEN_DEFAULT_ARGS to your .bash_profile with the commands you always want to run and modify your mvn file in the bin folder:

```
exec "$JAVACMD" \
$MAVEN_OPTS \
        -classpath "${M2_HOME}"/boot/plexus-classworlds-*.jar \
        "-Dclassworlds.conf=${M2_HOME}/bin/m2.conf" \
        "-Dmaven.home=${M2_HOME}"  \
        ${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} "$@"  \
        $MAVEN_DEFAULT_ARGS
```